# RoborFramework: how to send tag name into my keyword

Tags: python, robotframework

So I have this `test.robot` test file:

```
Test Setup       Test Setup

*** Test Cases ***
TestFlow_1
    [Tags]  my_tag regression
    Some Function  user password
```

In this test I have this `Some Function`  `keyword` that received several parameters and i want to send to this function one of my tags (`my_tag` or `regression`).
Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a built-in variable `${TEST TAGS}` - a list, that has all of them as its members; you can [read about it here](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#built-in-variables).

Thus if you want to pass the first tag as an argument:

```
Some Function  user password    ${test tags[0]}
```

Just make sure you do have tags (or, as many as the index you're passing), or you'll get IndexError.

Comment: Thats great, BTW any other command to pass the current test directory ? (or father)

Comment: Open the link in the answer; right in front of you, one of the first things is `${CURDIR}` :)